NEXTUI - Vercel doesn't display input errors from form submissions
I'm using Next UI's input components, but the error message isn't showing up, nor is it turning red. It only fails on Vercel; I've tested locally with 'dev' and after building, and it works perfectly
https://nextui.org/docs/components/input#with-error-message
The code of input is
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <Input
    autoComplete="off"
    id="nombre"
    onChange={changeDatos}
    value={servicio.nombre}
    label="Nombre"
    variant="bordered"
    type="text"
    isRequired={true}
  />
  ...
  ...
</form>;

In dev mode and in build mode in local show this

But in vercel only is focused.

"react": "18.2.0"
"next": "13.5.6"
"@nextui-org/react": "2.2.10"
Thanks :)
I've tried to populate the error message, which displays fine, but it remains fixed because I'm not using the 'isValid' field. I've also set that field to an empty string: 'errorMessage=""'

What library are you using to perform form validation (Yup, Zod, Formik etc.) ?
